# Outlook Add-in: Fetch attendees email address of selected meeting

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook, outlook-addin, appointment

I am developing a small Outlook add-in which will fetch all information about selected meeting and push this information to our in-house portal. Implementation is complete except RequiredAttendees part. Not sure why, but **Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem** object is only returning full names (as string) of the attendees. I am more interested in their email address of attendees. Here is my code snippet to replicate the issue:

```
try
{
    AppointmentItem appointment = null;
    for (int i = 1; i < Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count + 1; i++)
    {
        Object currentSelected = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[i];
        if (currentSelected is AppointmentItem)
        {
            appointment = currentSelected as AppointmentItem;
        }
    }

    // I am only getting attendees full name here
    string requiredAttendees = appointment.RequiredAttendees;

}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    LogException(ex);
}
```

I can see RequiredAttendees property is defined as string in **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._AppointmentItem** interface.

```
//
// Summary:
//     Returns a semicolon-delimited String (string in C#) of required attendee
//     names for the meeting appointment. Read/write.
[DispId(3588)]
string RequiredAttendees { get; set; }
```

I will greatly appreciate if someone can help me to resolve this issue or provide some around to get attendees email addresses.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this (not tested):

```
// Recipients are not zero indexed, start with one

for (int i = 1; i < appointment.Recipients.Count - 1; i++)
{
    string email = GetEmailAddressOfAttendee(appointment.Recipients[i]);
}


// Returns the SMTP email address of an attendee. NULL if not found.
function GetEmailAddressOfAttendee(Recipient TheRecipient)
{

    // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc513843%28v=office.12%29.aspx#AddressBooksAndRecipients_TheRecipientsCollection
    // for more info

    string PROPERTY_TAG_SMTP_ADDRESS = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E";

    if (TheRecipient.Type == (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo)
    {
        PropertyAccessor pa = TheRecipient.PropertyAccessor;
        return pa.GetProperty(PROPERTY_TAG_SMTP_ADDRESS);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: If we remove the if condition `if (TheRecipient.Type == (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo)`, then we can get email address of optional attendees as well.